# Here is prolog program that I can't get the result

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

What do I need to add to be able to get the output like this?

the sort targets the same years of experience which is 3

output

you would output:
6, 8, 34
or:
34, 8, 6

```
employee(a, b, 3, 8).
employee(c, d, 5, 19).
employee(e, f, 3, 34).
employee(g, h, 3, 6).

sortEmployes(YearsXP, Result) :-
    findall(FirstName-LastName-YearsXP-ID,
            employee(FirstName, LastName, YearsXP, ID),
            EmployesData),
    sort(2, @=<, EmployesData, Result).
```

Comment: Why those three numbers and not 19? What's the rule?

Comment: It's a 5 and not a 3. I hadn't answered SO questions in a while, it is such a wild ride. You really need to remember though (and this is a note to myself, too) that the students who ask for homework help on SO are a very tiny and specific minority. The huge majority is invisible on online forums and they just get it done (you'd assume).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler
the sort targets the same years of experience which is 3